# How do I get a nice dense folliage back on my Chinese Elm?

Tags: plant-health, pruning, soil, bonsai

I'm new here and quite new to growing bonsais! I'm in possession of a Chinese Elm, which I bought 3 months ago. It was held outside by the previous owner, so it had no leaves when it arrived here. I'm keeping it inside. After a month it started budding and the foliage was getting back and it looked dense. But.. I think I underwatered it so the tree almost lost all of its leaves again :(. Now it shows some shoots and leaves again but all the little older side branches don't seem to have any foliage. I live in the Netherlands and spring 'officially' started here 20th of March.

As can be seen in the picture below, the soil is not looking that great.. also the soil came loose from the sides of the pot?

I have a couple of questions and I hope the pictures will help clarify:

[image]

[image]

[image]

--> I don't use fertilizer yet, just ordered some.

Do I just let the trees grow this spring/summer without pruning it? Or should I keep pruning, to get a denser foliage?

With kind regards,

Martijn